# How to alert the message if select duplicate values in dynamic table using js?

Tags: javascript

I am selecting name in table and i click + button to create dynamic row and if i click same name it should alert the message. i tired so far but no response.

js code

```
<script>
$('#addMore3').on('click',function() { alert('ok');
var tableRows = $("#tb3 tbody tr");

  tableRows.each(function(n){
      var id = this.id;
      var row = $(this).val();

      tableRows.each(function(n){
         var $this;

         if(this.id != id){
            $this = $(this);

            if ($this.val() == row){
                alert('o');

            }
          }
       });
   });
});
</script>
```

View code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr >
    <td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove3'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>

<td><select  name="m1[]" id="name" class="form-control border-slate border-lg" style="height:35px; width:300px; " >
<option></option>
<?php foreach ($pname as $row ): ?> 
<option><?=$row->name ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
</select></td>
<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" id="addMore3" title="Add More Person"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

Comment: is it select tag of HTML or some custom dropdown in the table? does this name has unique id?

Comment: yes it is select tag have unique id i edited the code